# In Node.js imported txt file into a variable, but variable doesnt behave like a string

Tags: node.js, string, text-files, readfile

So in node.js I a have read a simple txt file into a variable, but when I want to call whichever string function like split or indexOf on the variable, it doesnt work.

if I do string.indexOf('whatever character'), I become always -1
And if i do string.splice('whichever separator') I become always this on the console: '\u0000s\u0000\r\u0000\n\u0000....'

the code:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
let emails = fs.readFileSync('../model/hotel-emails-with-links-exerc.txt', 'utf-8');
console.log(emails.split('/'));
console.log(emails.indexOf('http'));
```

this is the content of the file I read : 'youreamil@gmail.com|https://www.hotel-monte.at/de/zimmer-preise/pauschalen.html?offer=27'

If I do console.log(typeof emails) I get 'string' as normal.

However string variables whiches value was not imported from a txt file are working fine.

thanks for the suggestions

Comment: It looks like your text file is not utf8.

Comment: Mark_M you are a giant... thanks a lot it has worked. 
How did you recognise, it is is nor utf-8? Or I raise the question otherwise, what I kind of subject should I investigate that in the future I dont go into such failure again.
Thanks for your answer